# Change Sharepoint Calendar View from month to day

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, visual-web-part

How to change calendar view from month to day on button click event without ribbon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of straight away is because it changes view by URL, is to set the query string on a custom link to browse to it.

```
?CalendarPeriod=day
```

You probably need to define the view and date as well (Look at the QueryString when you click the ribbon)